# netapp filer supports clustered approach?

Tags: cluster-computing, netapp

Using Net app filer technology, does it supports clustered environment ?
if a common mount is shared across 1000 servers, if any maintenance on the filers will it make sure not to effect the application ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be connected to a clustered system.

The storage will keep serving NFS exports as the surviving controller or node was configured properly for takeover and giveback.

You may check the NetApp high-availability guide available at support.netapp.com